# NullReference Exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I'm getting `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Exception with below code.

```
   string avblCount = "0";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT.ToString() as string))
    {
         avblCount = item.PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT.ToString();
    }
```

Exception occurred from this line.

`if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT.ToString() as string))`

How can i fix this ?

Comment: item.PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT.ToString() as string) why ? do only as string it won't throw error

Comment: `item` or `CAPSLOCKHAPPYPROPERTY` is null, edit, why not just check if these are null instead of converting it to a string first?

Comment: does every part of item.PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT exist? What if for example PART_AVAILABILITY is null?

Comment: first tell tem.PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT is the null ?

Comment: _"How can i fix this?"_ - by searching the web. There's thousands of questions on this error on SO alone. Try to understand what the error means.

Comment: If you program in C# you absolutely positively must learn what a NullReferenceException is, how they come about, how they present themselves at runtime, how you can handle them, mitigate them and finally avoid them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or more of these entities are null:

- item
- item.PART_AVAILABILITY
- item.PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT

You should check which one is, and then act accordingly

Comment: Are you serious? If item is null, then the 3 are nulls. If item is not null but PART_AVAILABILTY is, then there are 2 nulls. If item and PART_AVAILABILTY aren't null, then AVAIL_COUNT is.

Comment: Exactly: they lead to a NullReferenceEx as per question. Is it just a flame or a dictionary-check?

Comment: Well, I won't argue nomore, but in my opinion if item is null, all its properties are "undefined": there is no "undefined" key-word in .NET, and obviously it has no sense to enter into reflection to check if a property is available in a given object. So, i used "null" in a unspecific way, but you're right: undeclared/undefined != null to a compiler eyes :)